Weyl crystal with broken time reversal symmetry (TRS) and spin-momentum locking
We know that the stability of Weyl points crucially requires that the bands involved are non-degenerate. Otherwise, there can be terms that cause band hybridization within the degenerate subspaces and in that way produce an energy gap. Non-degenerate bands require either time-reversal symmetry or inversion (parity) breaking. One way to break TRS is with magnetization (FM or AFM). But this confused me a little when we consider the existence of spin-momentum locking, because in the case of broken TRS, the spin symmetries with momentum are also broken.

In this specific case, what would protect the existence of spin-momentum locking in this system? Could it be due to the strong coupling limit of the spin-orbit coupling interaction?
