How does time-reversal symmetry breaking work in a Weyl crystal?
In a Weyl crystal, we can break the TRS (Time-Reversal Symmetry) by introducing FM or AFM atoms, and this breaking occurs due to the emergence of spontaneous magnetization in the material (I think), and consequently this leads to the breaking of degeneracy in the electronic bands, and also leading to a separation of the Weyl nodes in the space of moments, and this is very reminiscent of the Zeeman effect (spontaneous hall effect, which is more likely). Would this physical analogy/explanation be correct? If I'm completely wrong, what would be the best description of this phenomenon?

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/810253/2451
